# Why this single layer network does'nt work

Tags: keras

I am trying following code (modified from https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/10/seven-steps-deep-learning-keras.html ):

```
def single_layer(input_shape, nb_classes): 
    print("input shape:", input_shape)
    print("print nb_classes:", nb_classes)

    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes, input_shape=input_shape, activation='softmax')) 

    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy') 
    model.summary()
    return model
```

However, when I try to fit this model with an `X_train` of dimensions `64,64,3` and 17 classes, following is the output with error:

```
input shape: (64, 64, 3)
print nb_classes: 17
Using TensorFlow backend.
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64, 64, 17)        68        
=================================================================
Total params: 68
Trainable params: 68
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
....
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 950, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 787, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 127, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (10396, 17)
```

Why this code is not working and how should it be modified to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the code in the link you posted to get more background information on what kind of data source it is that you are using.

However, a data source that is $60\times60\times3$ is described as being high dimensional. You have a total of 10,800 input features which need to be mapped down to 17 different classes. This is actually a very complex task and will not be successful using a single layer network. Such a simple network will not have enough parameters to capture the non-linearities between features in your input space.

That being said, if you insist on using a single layer network with a data of size $60\times60\times3$ with 17 input classes the code is as follows.

Let's first create some artificial data of the same dimension as your data

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000
x_train = np.zeros((n,64,64,3))
y_train = np.zeros((n,))
for i in range(n):
    x_train[i,:,:,:] = np.random.random((64,64,3))
    y_train[i] = np.random.randint(0,17)

x_train = x_train.reshape(n,64,64,3,)

n = 100
x_test = np.zeros((n,64,64,3))
y_test = np.zeros((n,))
for i in range(n):
    x_test[i,:,:,:] = np.random.random((64,64,3))
    y_test[i] = np.random.randint(0,17)

x_test = x_test.reshape(n,64,64,3,)

print('Training data: ', x_train.shape)
print('Training labels: ', y_train.shape)
print('Testing data: ', x_test.shape)
print('Testing labels: ', y_test.shape)
```

> (1000, 64, 64, 3) 
>   (1000,) 
>   (100, 64, 64, 3) 
>   (100,)

For a classification task we should convert our outputs to categorical vectors. Where we use one-hot encoding to identify the correct class.

```
import keras

# The known number of output classes.
num_classes = 17

# Convert class vectors to binary class matrices. This uses 1 hot encoding.
y_train_binary = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test_binary = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

We then build the model.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras import backend as K

input_shape = (64,64,3,)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(17, activation='softmax'))


model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

You can see the summary of the model by using

```
model.summary()
```

Then we can train this model using

```
batch_size = 128
epochs = 10
model.fit(x_train, y_train_binary,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test_binary))
```

This code works. However, the data is completely random thus the model cannot learn anything. However, even if your data is easily distinguishable, as I said above, I do not expect this model to be complex enough to distinguish such a large input space from 17 different possible classes.

If you post the data source you are using we can design a model to get a good result.

Comment: Very good explanation.